# How to use some other driving process than the WienerProcess?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, random-process

According to the following reference page

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItoProcess.html

> The driving process *dproc* can be any process that can be converted to
>   a standard Ito process

and

> Processes *proc* that can be converted to standard ItoProcess form
>   include OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess, GeometricBrownianMotionProcess,
>   StratonovichProcess, and ItoProcess.

However, it does not seem to work in my example:

```
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[
     t] == -x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w[t], 
  x[t], {x, 1}, t, 
  w \[Distributed] OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, 1, 1]]
RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}]
ListLinePlot[%, Filling -> Axis]
```

which resulted in the error:

RandomFunction::unsproc: The specification ItoProcess[[DifferentialD]x[t]==[DifferentialD]w[t]-[DifferentialD]t x[t],x[t],{x,1},t,w[Distributed]OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0,1,1]] is not a random process recognized by the system.

Note that in defining the ItoProcess proc like above, `w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0,1]` would work, but `w \[Distributed] OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, 1, 1]` does not.

Comment: As I understand it, the usage is like `proc = ItoProcess[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[0, 1, 1]]
path = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 2. Pi, 0.05}, 12, 
  Method -> "StochasticRungeKutta"]
ListLinePlot[path] `

Comment: @belisarius This piece of code did not successfully result in a graph. Otherwise, my question concerns the driving. In the definition of the ItoProcess, `w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]` works, but `w \[Distributed] OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, 1, 1]` does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to complete the specification of the driving process by providing an initial condition :

```
SeedRandom[6]
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == -x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
                   \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 1}, t, 
                   w \[Distributed] OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, 1, 1, 0]]
RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}]
ListLinePlot[%, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed I overlooked the issue with the initial condition. When one defines an equivalent to proc by a system of two SDE's (see the reference page of OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess), the necessity of complete initial conditions is obvious. The resulting error message unfortunately was not helpful.